# PhoneGap Build Android Prototype Missing Images

Tags: android, cordova, prototype, phonegap-build, justinmind

I used Justinmind Prototyper to create a mobile prototype with gestures. The prototype is a simple clickthrough with images embedded. I exported to HTML, zipped the file and uploaded to PhoneGap Build. The package does not include a config.xml file, since the Phonegap Build docs said one wasn't required.

When I open the .apk file on Android Galaxy S4, I see a plain HTML screen with links. When I click any link, I get this error message:

APPLICATION ERROR

There was a network error (file:///android_asset/www/screens/d12245cc-1680-458d-89dd-4f0d7fb22724)

I double-checked the images file to make sure they're all named and web-appropriate (PNGs). It just seems like the images aren't linked properly, although I can't figure it out from the HTML that Justinmind Prototyper generated.